# JS - Difference between $("#elementid") vs document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom

What are the differences, if any, between `$("#elementID")` vs `document.getElementById("elementID")`?
Can they both do the same things?

What are these things called? Objects?
i.e.
if I have `x = $("#elementID")`, what is x?
if I have `y = document.getElementById("elementID")`, what is y?

Comment: hmm that question didnt show up in my searches. thanks for the reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById("elementID")` is a call of the DOM function exposed by JavaScript for obtaining a reference to an element in your DOM.

`$("#elementID")` is a function call to the *jQuery* JavaScript library that does much the same thing, though the result is a jQuery object encapsulating said DOM element. I'm not going to go into detail about what that means: you can read the jQuery documentation to find out all about that.

Comment: this is true, $("#elementID") is a function that jquery created while document.getElementById("elementID") is a DOM function of javascript

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen: `$` is a function. `$("#elementID")` is a function call expression.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#elementID")` is a JQuery method that requires you to include JQuery.js on your page and the other is a native browser method.

Using `$("#elementID")` you can use JQuery to manipulate it. `document.getElementById` gives you the DOM element